# ownership vs own: How to use the in a sentence as to one complementing the other?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

**Scenario:**

I posted a photo on FB and someone asked me if the photo was taken by me. But the photo was copied from the web and I am not the one who captured it. So does my following sentence make some sense.

**I do not own the ownership of the capture that you mentioned?**

What is the difference between the words Own and Ownership?

Comment: Have you looked up those words in a dictionary?  Is there something specific about their meanings that is not clear to you?

Answer (score 2):

The word 'own' is a verb, while the word 'ownership' is a noun that describes the state of owning something. Using both words within the same sentence would be redundant.

With this in mind, here are various valid choices for your response:

1. I do not own the photo.
2. I do not have ownership of the photo.
3. I did not capture the photo.

Comment: ans 2.  ->   in the place of 'have' I put own. So, is it ok?

Comment: @Gt_R - Saying "I do not own ownership of the photo" sounds odd because "ownership" is just the noun version of "own" - even though "have" might have a very similar meaning to "own" it sounds more natural to use "have".